HTML form not populating correctly, What am I doing wrong?
I have a javascript application where I need to save the user selections in a HTML form that I need to retrun to the form when the user returns to the page with the form.  I have implemented solutions that I have found here on stackoverflow, in fact the code below that I am using comes from this link
Here are two versions of that code
function dataLoad() 
        {
            if (typeof(Storage)!== "undefined")
            {
                if (localStorage.getItem('settingsObject') !== null) 
                {
                    console.log("in dataLoad");
                    var inputParse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settingsObject'));
                    console.log(inputParse);
                    $.each(inputParse, function (key, value) {
                        var field = document.getElementById(key);
                        if(field.type == 'radio' || field.type == 'checkbox'){
                            field.checked = value;
                        }else{
                            field.value = value;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
            }
            
        }
                    
        function dataLoad() 
        {
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
            {
                if (localStorage.getItem('settingsObject') !== null) 
                {
                    alert("in dataLoad");
                    var inputParse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settingsObject'));
                    console.log(inputParse);
                    $.each(inputParse, function(key, value) {
                      var field = document.querySelector("[name=" + key + "]");
                      if (field.type == 'radio' || field.type == 'checkbox') {
                        field.checked = field.value == value;
                      } else {
                        field.value = value;
                      }
                    });
                }
                
            }
            else 
            {
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
            }

        }

Here is my form
<form id="settingsInput" class="dropdown contents" autocomplete="on" target="hiddeniFrame">
                
                <fieldset class="locfield">
                    <legend>Location<br></legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="location" value="auto" id="autoloc" checked><label for="autoloc"> Auto</label><br><hr class="settingsDivider">
                    <input type="radio" name="location" value="city" id="cityloc"><label for="cityloc"> City</label><br>
                    Select City:<br>
                    <select name="cities" class="locinput" style="width:6em">
                        <option value="0" selected>U.S. Cities</option>
                        <option value="1">Albuquerque, NM</option>
                        <option value="2">Anchorage, AK</option>
                        <option value="3">Atlanta, GA</option>
                        <option value="4">Austin, TX</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <span><label for="Citydst" style="font-size:15px">Daylight Saving?</label></span><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="CityDST" value="DST" id="Citydst"><br>
                    <hr class="settingsDivider">
                    
                    <input type="radio" name="location" value="manual" id="manualloc"><label for="manualloc"> Manual</label><br>
                    
                    Latitude:<br> <input type="number" name="latitude" maxlength="10" class="locinput" style="width:6em"><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="NS" value="north" id="North"><label for="North"> North</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="NS" value="south" id="South"><label for="South"> South</label><br>
                    Longitude:<br> <input type="number" name="longitude" class="locinput" style="width:6em"><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="EW" value="east" id="East"><label for="East"> East</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="EW" value="west" id="West"><label for="West"> West</label><br>
                    Elevation:<br> <input type="number" name="landelev" class="locinput" style="width:6em"><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="elevunits" value="feet" id="feet"><label for="feet"> Feet</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="elevunits" value="meters" id="meters"><label for="meters"> Meters</label><br>
                    Time Zone:<br> <select name="timezones">
                        <option value="-12">UTC-12</option>
                        <option value="-11">UTC-11</option>
                        <option value="-10">UTC-10</option>
                        <option value="-9">UTC-9</option>
                        <option value="-8">UTC-8</option>
                        <option value="-7">UTC-7</option>
                        <option value="-6">UTC-6</option>
                        <option value="-5">UTC-5</option>
                        <option value="-4">UTC-4</option>
                        <option value="-3">UTC-3</option>
                        <option value="-2">UTC-2</option>
                        <option value="-1">UTC-1</option>
                        <option value="0">UTC+0</option>
                        <option value="1">UTC+1</option>
                        <option value="2">UTC+2</option>
                        <option value="3">UTC+3</option>
                        <option value="4">UTC+4</option>
                        <option value="5">UTC+5</option>
                        <option value="6">UTC+6</option>
                        <option value="7">UTC+7</option>
                        <option value="8">UTC+8</option>
                        <option value="9">UTC+9</option>
                        <option value="10">UTC+10</option>
                        <option value="11">UTC+11</option>
                        <option value="12">UTC+12</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <span><label for="Manualdst" style="font-size:15px">Daylight Saving?</label></span><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ManualDST" value="DST" id="Manualdst">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="datefield">
                    <legend>Date</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="dateMode" value="auto" id="autodate" checked><label for="autodate"> Auto</label><br><hr class="settingsDivider">
                    <input type="radio" name="dateMode" value="manual" id="manualdate"><label for="manualdate"> Manual</label><br>
                    Select Date:<br>
                    <input type="date" name="dateInput" class="dateinput" style="width:6em"><br><hr class="settingsDivider">
                    <!--<label for="dst" style="font-size:15px">Daylight Saving?</label></span><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="DST" value="DST" id="dst"><span style="font-size: 13px">-->
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="prayerfield">
                    <legend>Prayers</legend>
                    <!--<span style="text-decoration: underline">Subh Cond:</span><br>-->
                    <span>Subh Cond:</span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="subhMode" value="12" id="subhurban" checked><span><label for="subhurban"> Urban</label></span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="subhMode" value="15" id="subhwild"><span style="font-size: 17px"><label for="subhwild"> Wilderness</label></span><br><hr class="settingsDivider">
                    <span class="dhuhurtext">Dhuhur Shadow:</span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="dhuhurMode" value="42" id="dhuhursandal"><span style="font-size: 15px"><label for="dhuhursandal"> Sandal Strap</label></span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="dhuhurMode" value="21" id="dhuhurhand" checked><span style="font-size: 17px"><label for="dhuhurhand"> Hand Span</label></span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="dhuhurMode" value="7" id="dhuhurfoot"><span style="font-size: 17px"><label for="dhuhurfoot"> Foot Span</label></span><br><hr class="settingsDivider">
                    <!--<span style="text-decoration: underline">Asr Shadow:</span><br>-->
                    <span>Asr Shadow:</span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="asrMode" value="1" id="asrmajority" checked><span style="font-size: 20px"><label for="asrmajority"> Majority</label></span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="asrMode" value="2" id="asrhanafi"><span><label for="asrhanafi"> Hanafi</label></span><br><hr class="settingsDivider">
                    <!--<span style="text-decoration: underline">Isha Cond:</span><br>-->
                    <span>Isha Cond:</span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="ishaMode" value="12" id="ishaurban"><span><label for="ishaurban"> Urban</label></span><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="ishaMode" value="15" id="ishawild" checked><span style="font-size: 17px"><label for="ishawild"> Wilderness</label></span><br>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="set-section">
                    <button type="button" name="prayertimes" value=" Save " onclick="chooseMethod(this.form)">Save</button>
                </div>
                <div class="update-section">
                    <button type="button" name="updateprayertimes" value=" Update " onclick="chooseMethod(this.form)">Update</button>
                </div>
                <div class="reset-section">
                    <button type="reset" value=" Reset ">Reset</button>
                </div>
                <script>
                    document.getElementById("settingsInput").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                    //Rest of your js code here...
                </script>
            </form>

I have had more success with the bottom version than the top version.  Actually the top version does not seem to repopulate any of the elements, while the bottom version does a better job, but fails to populate the radio buttons named "location" and the radio buttons named "auto", "cities", and "manual", as well as the radio buttons named "NS" and "EW".  Sometimes the radio button for "dateMode" doe not get repopulated.  The funny thing is that the radio buttons named "subhMode", "dhuhurMode", "asrMode", and "ishaMode" always get repopulated.
What am I doing wrong?

there is 2 function dataLoad()...

Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

I have tried to solve this.  I have included both versions of the function dataLoad() that I have tried.  I mentioned that in my description.  I have searched SO for an answer and I found two topics, each had one of the two versions of dataLoad().  As I mentioned my write up the top version does not populate the form and the bottom one populates the form partially but in a weird way such that some radio buttons are populated and some are not.  Is the problem in my form or in the function to populate the form?

Here is what the CacheData() function I am using (from the same link that I obtained the dataLoad() function) gives after I pick something different from the default form settings.
{location: 'city', cities: '1', CityDST: 'DST', latitude: '', longitude: '', …}
CityDST
:
"DST"
asrMode
:
"1"
cities
:
"1"
dateInput
:
""
dateMode
:
"auto"
dhuhurMode
:
"21"
ishaMode
:
"15"
landelev
:
""
latitude
:
""
location
:
"city"
longitude
:
""
subhMode
:
"12"
timezones
:
"-12"

Then I update the app and have loadData() repopulate the form and here is what I see on the console.log
{cities: '1', CityDST: 'DST', latitude: '', longitude: '', landelev: '', …}
CityDST
:
"DST"
asrMode
:
"1"
cities
:
"1"
dateInput
:
""
dateMode
:
"auto"
dhuhurMode
:
"21"
ishaMode
:
"15"
landelev
:
""
latitude
:
""
longitude
:
""
subhMode
:
"12"
timezones
:
"-12"
you can see that location, which should be 'city' as it was saved, is not being populated.  Why is that happening?

In fact location as an item is not even showing up in the inputParse object but it was in the formData object that was saved in the first place.  Why is that happening?
